# Почему координата фиксируется

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть корабль который должен постоянно находиться на координатах (x, y, -3) чтобы летать перед фоном и другими объектами, у меня есть Canvas UI в котором находяться все объекты(при изменение UI меняеться размер всех объектов в нем с пропорциями), но почему-то когда я при старте игры оставляю это в скрипте:

```
public Camera camera;
public GameObject UI;
public void Start()
    {
        float x = (float)Screen.width;
        float y = (float)Screen.height;
        camera.orthographicSize = y / 2;
        UI.transform.localScale = new Vector2(x / 1280f, y / 720f); //< эта строчка
    }
```

То корабль как будто в FixedUpdate начинает менять позицию z на 0, и ее не получается изменить, без этой строчки все работает как надо, по какой причине это может быть?

Comment: я вижу что вы устанавливаете vector2, а как же координата по z, которая -3, или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: А кстати, зачем вам масштабирующий коэффициент-то -3 понадобился?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ in the Q данный код маштабирует canvas под камеру которая растянута на весь экран, темболее это 2d игра и в параметре scale есть только x / y, и проблема не в маштабе, а где корабль находиться его позиция z должна быть -3, но из за той строчки она становиться 0

Comment: @trollingchar , -3 это его z позиция, а не параметр scale, игра 2d , scale принимает только x / y, вопрос про позицию корабля по оси z, ничто в коде не должно менять ее , но при этом эта строчка почемуто ее меняет

Comment: @NeulovimFox да, я не углядел что это scale, может быть проблема в том что использование 2д трансформов почему то предполагает что все другие параметры тоже в 2д. объект про который идет речь наследник этой канаы?

Comment: Кстати а почему все объекты не в мире, а в канвасе? Может будет проще world space canvas сделать для них и не заморачиваться с масштабом?

Comment: @NeulovimFox я плохо понимаю о чем речь, без какой либо визуализации или воспроизводимого примера

Comment: @NeulovimFox я вижу на скрине 3д трансформы и в скейле по z вообще 0 а не 1, это как? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выбора очередности отрисовки необходимо использовать `sorting layer` и `order in layer`, чем order больше, тем элемент ближе к наблюдателю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: а координаты по оси z трогать не стоит для 2д игры.